# Python threading - Stopping a thread from another function

Tags: python, multithreading

I've started playing with threading in python, after looking at lots of tutorials I finally have threading working in my project - however I've not found any examples where the thread is stopped from another function. So I can start the thread, it works fine, CSV is written correctly but I can't stop it. I get the following error from the stop function:

> File "./blackboxv1.1.py", line 162, in stop_csv_logging
>       csv_thread.join()
>   NameError: global name 'csv_thread' is not defined

I've attached my code, it's only a snippet from much larger bit of code but everything is there I think should be relevant. The code essentially writes GPS data to a CSV file for logging GPS and accelerometer data, its called from a menu which calls the start and stop functions.

This bit in each function catches the key presses from the buttons on the LCD board and work fine.

```
sleep(0.5)
  while 1:
        if lcd.is_pressed(0):
           break
        else:
```

I'm fairly new to Python so this is a steep curve ..

```
class WriteCSV:
    def __init__(self):
            self._running = True

        def terminate(self):
            self._running = False

    def run(self):
            # create unique filename based on date/time
            new_file = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.csv")
            file_path = "/home/pi/scripts/gps/log_data/"
            new_filename = file_path + new_file
            # Set headers for csv
            headers = ['TimeStamp', 'Speed', 'Lat', 'Lon', 'Alt', 'Climb', 'Acc_X', 'Accl_Y']
            # needed to get accl data
            accel = lsm.readAccelerationsG()
            # create file and set headers then close
            outfile = open(new_filename, 'a+')
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow(headers)
            outfile.close()
        while self._running:
                 # reopen existing file
                 outfile = open(new_filename, 'a+')
                 writer = csv.writer(outfile)
                 # unique timestamp needed for each row
                 time_stamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                 # need to round down the g force numbers
                 accel.x = round(accel.x,1)
                 accel.y = round(accel.y,1)
                 # Set Row
                 row = [time_stamp, gpsd.fix.speed, gpsd.fix.latitude, gpsd.fix.longitude, gpsd.fix.altitude, gpsd.fix.climb, accel.x, accel.y]
                 # Write Row
                 writer.writerow(row)
                 # Close file
                 outfile.close()
                 # set sleep of 1 sec
                 sleep(1)


#========================================================
# Start CSV Logging
#========================================================

def start_csv_logging():
# create an instance of class WriteCSV
# create a thread using the instance
# then start the thread
  sleep(0.5)
  while 1:
        if lcd.is_pressed(0):
           break
        else:
       global csv_log
       csv_log = WriteCSV() 
       # create the thread and start run()
       csv_thread = threading.Thread(target=csv_log.run) 
       # start it up
       csv_thread.start()
       lcd.clear()
       lcd.message("Starting Log ..")
       sleep(2)
       lcd.clear()
       lcd.message("Logging!")
       break    

#========================================================
# Stop CSV Logging
#========================================================

def stop_csv_logging():
  sleep(0.5)
  while 1:
        if lcd.is_pressed(0):
           break
        else:
       # Signal termination
       csv_log.terminate()
       csv_thread.join()      
       # Wait for termination
       lcd.clear()
           lcd.message("Stopping ....")
       sleep(2)
       lcd.clear()
       lcd.message("Log Stopped!")
       sleep(2)
       break    
#========================================================
```

Comment: Well, what do you expect? You need to make the thread global so the first function can set it's value.

Comment: Yep that fixed it - thanks. In case someone else comes looking the fix is below:
    global csv_log
    csv_log = WriteCSV() 
    # create the thread and start run()
    global csv_thread
    csv_thread = threading.Thread(target=csv_log.run)